# DB2 Stored Procedure Not able to assign data to a variable

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, db2-luw

I have a simple stored procedure to calculate the sum of salaries of employees, sum of their squares and number of rows.

This is the stored procedure I have written:

I get an error in fetching the number of rows from the database and assigning it to a variable. What do I do? Using DB2 11.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helps to *specify* the exact error code when asking questions (don't write get an error, do write instead 'get error SQL0104N ...`.

Your mistake is that you have not followed the [documented](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0004239.html) order for SQL statements in compound SQL blocks.

The SELECT statement can only appear after any cursor definitions, local procedures , and handlers if you have any.

So move the statement `SELECT COUNT(*) INTO TOTAL_ROWS FROM EMPLOYEE;` so that it appears *after* the `DECLARE CURSOR1 ...` line, the try to recompile.